# I Have problem on photon pun2, the players has being instantiated but one divces can't you see two players

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile, multiplayer, photon

I try to sync two players with same room but I faced a small issue, the issue is when I play the game on two devices the master client device showen two players and movment of the player of other device"That What I want", but the other device just show single player and don't show the materclient player, and the movment of not masterclient device show player movment on the masterclient device.

This is my scripts:
Connet script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;

public class ConnectToTheServer : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    //Our player name
    string playerName = "Player 1";
    //Users are separated from each other by gameversion (which allows you to make breaking changes).
    string gameVersion = "0.9";
    //The list of created rooms
    List<RoomInfo> createdRooms = new List<RoomInfo>();
    //Use this name when creating a Room
    string roomName = "Room 1";
    Vector2 roomListScroll = Vector2.zero;
    bool joiningRoom = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //This makes sure we can use PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel() on the master client and all clients in the same room sync their level automatically
        PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;

        if (!PhotonNetwork.IsConnected)
        {
            //Set the App version before connecting
            PhotonNetwork.PhotonServerSettings.AppSettings.AppVersion = gameVersion;
            // Connect to the photon master-server. We use the settings saved in PhotonServerSettings (a .asset file in this project)
            PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
        }
    }

    public override void OnDisconnected(DisconnectCause cause)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnFailedToConnectToPhoton. StatusCode: " + cause.ToString() + " ServerAddress: " + PhotonNetwork.ServerAddress);
    }

    public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnConnectedToMaster");
        //After we connected to Master server, join the Lobby
        PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby(TypedLobby.Default);
    }

    public override void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> roomList)
    {
        Debug.Log("We have received the Room list");
        //After this callback, update the room list
        createdRooms = roomList;
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Window(0, new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 450, Screen.height / 2 - 200, 900, 400), LobbyWindow, "Lobby");
    }

    void LobbyWindow(int index)
    {
        //Connection Status and Room creation Button
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

        GUILayout.Label("Status: " + PhotonNetwork.NetworkClientState);

        if (joiningRoom || !PhotonNetwork.IsConnected || PhotonNetwork.NetworkClientState != ClientState.JoinedLobby)
        {
            GUI.enabled = false;
        }

        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();

        //Room name text field
        roomName = GUILayout.TextField(roomName, GUILayout.Width(250));

        if (GUILayout.Button("Create Room", GUILayout.Width(125)))
        {
            if (roomName != "")
            {
                joiningRoom = true;

                RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions();
                roomOptions.IsOpen = true;
                roomOptions.IsVisible = true;
                roomOptions.MaxPlayers = (byte)2; //Set any number

                PhotonNetwork.JoinOrCreateRoom(roomName, roomOptions, TypedLobby.Default);
            }
        }

        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        //Scroll through available rooms
        roomListScroll = GUILayout.BeginScrollView(roomListScroll, true, true);

        if (createdRooms.Count == 0)
        {
            GUILayout.Label("No Rooms were created yet...");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < createdRooms.Count; i++)
            {
                GUILayout.BeginHorizontal("box");
                GUILayout.Label(createdRooms[i].Name, GUILayout.Width(400));
                GUILayout.Label(createdRooms[i].PlayerCount + "/" + createdRooms[i].MaxPlayers);

                GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();

                if (GUILayout.Button("Join Room"))
                {
                    joiningRoom = true;

                    //Set our Player name
                    PhotonNetwork.NickName = playerName;

                    //Join the Room
                    PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(createdRooms[i].Name);
                }
                GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            }
        }

        GUILayout.EndScrollView();

        //Set player name and Refresh Room button
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

        GUILayout.Label("Player Name: ", GUILayout.Width(85));
        //Player name text field
        playerName = GUILayout.TextField(playerName, GUILayout.Width(250));

        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();

        GUI.enabled = (PhotonNetwork.NetworkClientState == ClientState.JoinedLobby || PhotonNetwork.NetworkClientState == ClientState.Disconnected) && !joiningRoom;
        if (GUILayout.Button("Refresh", GUILayout.Width(100)))
        {
            if (PhotonNetwork.IsConnected)
            {
                //Re-join Lobby to get the latest Room list
                PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby(TypedLobby.Default);
            }
            else
            {
                //We are not connected, estabilish a new connection
                PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
            }
        }

        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        if (joiningRoom)
        {
            GUI.enabled = true;
            GUI.Label(new Rect(900 / 2 - 50, 400 / 2 - 10, 100, 20), "Connecting...");
        }
    }

    public override void OnCreateRoomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnCreateRoomFailed got called. This can happen if the room exists (even if not visible). Try another room name.");
        joiningRoom = false;
    }

    public override void OnJoinRoomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnJoinRoomFailed got called. This can happen if the room is not existing or full or closed.");
        joiningRoom = false;
    }

    public override void OnJoinRandomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnJoinRandomFailed got called. This can happen if the room is not existing or full or closed.");
        joiningRoom = false;
    }

    public override void OnCreatedRoom()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnCreatedRoom");
        //Set our player name
        PhotonNetwork.NickName = playerName;
        //Load the Scene called GameLevel (Make sure it's added to build settings)
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("Game");
    }

    public override void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnJoinedRoom");
    }
}
```

Spawn Players Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class SpwanPlayers : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public GameObject playerPrefab;
    public Transform spawnPoint1, spawnPoint2;

    void Start()
    {
        if (!PhotonNetwork.InRoom)
        {
            Debug.Log("Not in a room, returning to Lobby");
            UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene("Lobby");
            return;
        }

        if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
        {
            PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(playerPrefab.name, spawnPoint1.position, Quaternion.identity, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(playerPrefab.name, spawnPoint2.position, Quaternion.identity, 0);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount == 2)
        {
            GO();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Wait for other players");
        }
    }

    void GO()
    {
        if (!PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient) return;

        Debug.Log("Starting the game!");
        // Add your game start logic here
    }

    public override void OnLeftRoom()
    {
        UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene("Lobby");
    }
}
```

And sync script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class PlayerSyncing : MonoBehaviourPun, IPunObservable
{
    //List of the scripts that should only be active for the local player (ex. PlayerController, MouseLook etc.)
    public MonoBehaviour[] localScripts;
    //List of the GameObjects that should only be active for the local player (ex. Camera, AudioListener etc.)
    public GameObject[] localObjects;
    //Values that will be synced over network
    Vector3 latestPos;
    Quaternion latestRot;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            //Player is local
        }
        else
        {
            //Player is Remote, deactivate the scripts and object that should only be enabled for the local player
            for (int i = 0; i < localScripts.Length; i++)
            {
                localScripts[i].enabled = false;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < localObjects.Length; i++)
            {
                localObjects[i].SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
    {
        if (stream.IsWriting)
        {
            //We own this player: send the others our data
            stream.SendNext(transform.position);
            stream.SendNext(transform.rotation);
        }
        else
        {
            //Network player, receive data
            latestPos = (Vector3)stream.ReceiveNext();
            latestRot = (Quaternion)stream.ReceiveNext();
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (!photonView.IsMine)
        {
            //Update remote player (smooth this, this looks good, at the cost of some accuracy)
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, latestPos, Time.deltaTime * 5);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, latestRot, Time.deltaTime * 5);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone to help me fix this problem soon <3

I hope someone to help me fix this problem soon <3

Comment: To attract answers, please consider proofreading and editing your question for clarity.